# Link to the current page with a specific get url param

Tags: html, url, get, hyperlink

I have a page which by default has a plain looking theme.  In order to swap between one of 5 themes the url parameter agency=x where is the name of the theme must set.

So if the default url of my page was

http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html?&some.param=123&someother.param=321

I need to have a url that would link to

http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html?&some.param=123&someotherparam=321**&agency=2**

Keep in mind that some.param and someother.param are arbitrary, users could hit this page with all sorts of crazy get params, I just need to (if possible) link to itself with the addtional get parameter.

I can always render this out dynamically via a servlet or jsp but if there is a way to do this with standard links/hrefs it would be much better.

Any ideas?

Comment: Markup for all themes matches?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of both, but I would do, in the `<head>` element:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="agency<%= the agency %>.css" />
```

And have `agency.css` for the default, `agency1.css` for theme 1 and so on.

Comment: So essentially just dynamically generate the url?

Comment: Yes, that's all. It's not the neatest solution but it's probably the simplest and encourages content/behaviour/presentation separation.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with javascript.

On all hrefs add an onclick callback (using document.getElementsByTagName('a')) which parses window.location and adds it to the href on the fly.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea.  Client side dependencies always bite you later.